# How to translate superagent to axios?

Tags: axios, superagent

I have some upload working for superagent. It involves posting to an api for cloudinary. My question is how do I do the same thing with axios. I'm not sure what `superagent.attach` and `superagent.field` relate to in axios.

Basically when I make the post request I need to attach all these fields to the request or else I get bad request and I want to do this in axios not superagent as I am switching over to axios.

Here are all the params:

```
    const image = files[0];

    const cloudName = 'tbaustin';
    const url = `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${cloudName}/image/upload`;

    const timestamp = Date.now()/1000;
    const uploadPreset = 'cnh7rzwp';

    const paramsStr = `timestamp=${timestamp}&upload_preset=${uploadPreset}ORor-6scjYwQGpNBvMW2HGMkc8k`;

    const signature = sha1(paramsStr);
    const params = {
      'api_key': '177287448318217',
      'timestamp': timestamp,
      'upload_preset': uploadPreset,
      'signature': signature
    }
```

Here is the superagent post request:

```
let uploadRequest = superagent.post(url)
    uploadRequest.attach('file', image);

    Object.keys(params).forEach((key) => {
      uploadRequest.field(key, params[key]);
    });

    uploadRequest.end((err, res) => {
      if(err) {
        alert(err);
        return
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use FromData as follows:

```
  var url = `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${cloudName}/upload`;
  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append("upload_preset", unsignedUploadPreset);
  fd.append("tags", "browser_upload"); // Optional - add tag for image admin in Cloudinary
  fd.append("signature", signature);
  fd.append("file", file);
  const config = {
    headers: { "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest" },
    onUploadProgress: function(progressEvent) {
      // Do something with the native progress event
    }
  };
  axios.post(url, fd, config)
            .then(function (res) {
              // File uploaded successfully
              console.log(res.data);
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
              console.error('err', err);
            });
```

See full example [here](https://codepen.io/eitanp461/pen/zzXEzb)